# What's the meaning of "it's kind/nice of you?

Tags: conversation

My teacher had told me that "it's kind/nice of you" is an expression of praising but I have heard this phrase from others as an expression of thankfulness.Which one is correct?

Answer (score 18):

It has both meanings of praise and thankfulness

> That's very **kind** of you
>   That's very **nice** of you
>   That's very **thoughtful** of you
>   That's very **sweet** of you

often accompanied by "**thank you**"

> Thank you, that's very kind of you.

Comment: One way to understand the wording is to **invert the word order**, just like with "whom" sentences.  The trick is that there is a verb missing (and replaced by the word "that").   Here are some examples -- first, pick the verb "to help".  Then you have: **"To help is very kind of you."**  Or:  **"To clean your room is very nice of you."**   **"To buy flowers is very sweet of you."**  Once you have this wording, you can see that `of you` can be removed from the sentence without changing the meaning too much.